# How can I add value to pos?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to add 10 to the position of my layout, when the condition is True.

How can I write that? This is my approach:

```py
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if "-" in str(touch.dy):
        if touch.dy < -4.0:
            self.pos += (0,(-2850 + 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.y += 10`, or similarly for `self.x += 10`, or something like `self.pos = (self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + 10)`.

Also your line `if "-" in str(touch.dy):` is both unnecessary and bad style, your next line is the correct way to compare numbers.